# Test case for testing a jersey web resource using grizzle is giving me 404

Tags: jersey-test-framework

I tried below way which is working fine

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerException;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
    import org.junit.Test;

    import com.mkyong.rest.HelloWorldService;

    public class HelloWorldServiceTest extends JerseyTest{

        @Path("hello")
        public static class HelloResource {
            @GET
            public String getHello() {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Application configure() {
            return new ResourceConfig(HelloResource.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
            return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
        }

        @Override
        protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
            return ServletDeploymentContext.forPackages(
                    getClass().getPackage().getName()).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void testSingleNode() throws Exception {
            final String hello = target("hello").request().get(String.class);
            assertEquals("Hello World!", hello);
        }
        }
```

When i tried to replace the resource with resource which is outside of this test class and package like below

```
   package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.mkyong.rest.HelloWorldService;

public class HelloWorldServiceTest extends JerseyTest{

    @Path("hello")
    public static class HelloResource {
        @GET
        public String getHello() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldService.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return ServletDeploymentContext.forPackages(
                getClass().getPackage().getName()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleNode() throws Exception {
        final String hello = target("hello").path("Test").request().get(String.class);
        assertEquals("Jersey say : Test", hello);
    }
    }
```

HelloWorldService.java

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

RestApplication.java

```
      package rest;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.mkyong.rest.HelloWorldService;

public class RestApplication extends Application{

      @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

            s.add(HelloWorldService.class);
            return s;
        }


}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rs-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>rest.RestApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>rs-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I got an exception

```
   javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:917)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:770)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:423)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:396)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:296)
at test.HelloWorldServiceTest.testSingleNode(HelloWorldServiceTest.java:48)
```

Can any one correct me where i went wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this

```
@Override
protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    return ServletDeploymentContext.forPackages(
            getClass().getPackage().getName()).build();
}
```

The `forPackages` is saying what package to scan for `@Path` and `@Provider` annotated classes, and automatically register them. The reason it works in the first example is that the resource class (the class annotated with `@Path` is in the `getClass().getPackage().getName()` package.

This method

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldService.class);
}
```

is never called, because you override the `getDeploymentContext()`. Normally, if you don't override that method, it will call the `configure` method to register the application with the deployment context. But you neve do this.

So instead of the `forPackages`, you should use one of the `ServletDeploymentContext.builder` methods, that accept an `Application` class

```
return ServletDeploymentContext.builder(configure()).build()

return ServletDeploymentContext.builder(RestApplication.class).build();
```

OR

```
@Override
public ResourceConfig configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldService.class);
}

@Override
public ServletDeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    return SerlvetDeploymentContext.forServlet(new ServletContainer(configure));
}
```

One thing to note it that you only need to override the `getTestContainerFactory` and the `configureDeployment` if you wan to set up a servlet environment. Meaning, you need to use servlet APIs like `HttpServletRequest`, `ServletContext`, etc, in your application. If you don't need a servlet environment, just overriding `configure` is enough.

Comment: Hi @peeskille, Thank you for your response.. I tried what ever you mentioned in the comment,
`ServletDeploymentContext.builder(configure()).build() and ServletDeploymentContext.builder(RestApplication.class).build();` gave me HTTP 404 Not found

These below cases are working fine.. 

`return ServletDeploymentContext.forPackages(HelloWorldService.class.getPackage().getName()).build();`

`return ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldService.class))).build();`
Thank you once again